# LogMeIn From Mac To a PC - Wheres Home and End Keys

Tags: mac, logmein

I have a Mac at home and a PC at the office. To access my work PC we use LogMeIn. It works pretty well, except I have not been able to figure out how to use the HOME and END keys while accessing my work PC from the Mac via LogMeIn.

I need to be able to jump to the beginning and ending of lines in a text document. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of the first answers I posted...

Macs have this function, just not a default button for it. Simply use any of these for special keys:

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> = home

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> = end

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> = Page Up

<kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> = Page Down

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> = Top of Document

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> = Bottom of Document

(Sometime home and top of document get switched around, it depends on program, but generally the above is correct)

Comment: Did you really mean command+downarrow for "Top of Document" or is that a typo?

Comment: Thank you. I only use the mac for xcode, which fn + --> moves you to end of file and command + --> moves you to end of line.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [LogMeIn manual](https://secure.logmein.com/welcome/documentation/EN/pdf/Ignition/LogMeIn_Ignition_UserGuide_iPhone.pdf) (warning: PDF), you first click the button on the LogMeIn toolbar to pop up the on-screen keyboard.  Then click the **Extra keys** button.  From there, you can "swipe left and right" to select the keys you need.  Not exactly fast, but at least it's workable.